# Windows system color picker app?

Tags: windows-7

It's seems both Linux and Mac OS X have a built-in color picker tool. Are there any apps for Windows that can open something like the below and be assigned to a global hotkey?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pixeur](https://pixeur.en.softonic.com/) is a nice neat little app, which amongst other things, maintains a history of captured colours.

[image: Pixeur colour picker]

Answer (score 1):

ColorPic from Iconico is great; it has swappable auto-saving pallets, averaging, & multiple mixers.  http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/

[image]